# How to Add recurring events programmatically?

Tags: android

I am developing an application for adding events to calendar. I am using following code to insert recurring event but it force closes the application with an error:

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DTEND and DURATION cannot both be null for an event."

code:

```
ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
event.put("calendar_id", 1);
event.put("title", "Event Title");
event.put("description", "Event Desc");
event.put("eventLocation", "Event Location");
event.put("dtstart", Long.parseLong("1315432844000"));
event.put("rrule", "FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;BYDAY=WE");
event.put("allDay", 1);   // 0 for false, 1 for true
event.put("eventStatus", 1);
event.put("hasAlarm", 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true
Uri url = getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a DTEND or DURATION like the error helpfully suggests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is my corrected code..working fine :)

```
public class mainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Uri eventsUri;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) {

            eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
        } else {

            eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
        }

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
        event.put("calendar_id", 1);
        event.put("title", "Event Title");
        event.put("description", "Event Desc");
        event.put("eventLocation", "Event Location");
        event.put("dtstart",cal.getTimeInMillis());
        event.put("rrule", "FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;BYDAY=WE");
        event.put("allDay", 1);   // 0 for false, 1 for true
        event.put("eventStatus", 1);
        event.put("hasAlarm", 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true
        event.put("duration","P3600S");
        Uri url = getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871921/add-weekly-event-to-calendar

Comment: Throwing `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Event values must include an eventTimezone`. Worked when added `event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE);`

Comment: Put this line and it'll work just fine - `event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().id)`

Answer (score 2):

From [CalendarContract.Events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html)
...

**Insert**

When inserting a new event the following fields must be included:

> dtstart
>
> dtend if the event is non-recurring
>
> duration if the event is recurring
>
> rrule or rdate if the event is recurring
>
> eventTimezone
>
> a calendar_id

---

> So for a recurring event you must have
>   dtstart,duration,rrule/rdate,eventTimezone,calendar_id.

So in your case

> remove dtend!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you should set DTEND and DURATION to some valid value, since "DTEND and DURATION cannot both be null for an event."

Answer (score 0):

Add **Recurring Event** in Android **Calendar** programatically:

```
Calendar calStart = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
calEnd.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);

ContentResolver cr = mCtx.getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, calStart.getTimeInMillis());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, calEnd.getTimeInMillis());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Event Title");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Event Description");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID,Long.parseLong("Your_Calendar_Id"));

    if (Your_Event_Is_Daily) {
        values.put("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY");
    } else if (Your_Event_Is_Weekly) {
        values.put("rrule", "FREQ=WEEKLY");
    } else if (Your_Event_Is_Monthly) {
        values.put("rrule", "FREQ=MONTHLY");
    } else if (Your_Event_Is_Yearly) {
        values.put("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
    }

Uri uri1 = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
String eventID = uri1.getLastPathSegment();
Log.i("Event Id", eventID);
```

Here **eventID** is **Event Reference Id**. If you need to **update** or **delete** event than **eventID** will be use.

**Done**